# How to find epoch for last month same day?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, epoch

I have below PLSQL code which finds the epoch for last month same day, however it fails when I run it on month end for 31 and 01 days.

```
 SET serveroutput ON
    DECLARE
      vDay        VARCHAR2(30) := '&Enter_current_day';
      vDate        VARCHAR2(30);
      vEpoch       NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      vDate  := TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM')||'-'||vDay||'-'||TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY');
      vEpoch := (ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(vDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), -1) - TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60;
      vDate  := TO_DATE(vDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
      dbms_output.put_line('Current Date: '||to_number(vDay)||' Epoch: '||vEpoch||' Date: '||vDate);
    END;
```

e.g. if todays date is,

```
A. 30-Sep and if I enter '31' then it should return epoch for the 01-Sep
B. 30-Sep and if I enter '01' then it should return epoch for the 01-Sep
C. 30-Mar and if I enter '31' then it should return epoch for the 01-Mar
D. 30-Mar and if I enter '01' then it should return epoch for the 01-Mar
```

Comment: for cases B and D, did you really want the first of the month? Shouldn't it be the last day of the month?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would do the trick?

```
DECLARE
  vday    VARCHAR2(30) := '&Enter_current_day';
  vdate   DATE;
  vepoch  NUMBER;
  v_today DATE := SYSDATE - 30;
BEGIN
  vdate  := to_date(to_char(v_today, 'MM') || '-' ||
                      least(to_number(vday),
                      to_number(to_char(last_day(v_today), 'dd'))) || '-' ||
                      to_char(v_today, 'YYYY'),
                    'MM-DD-YYYY');
  vepoch := (add_months(vdate, -1) -
               to_date('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60;

  dbms_output.put_line('Current Date: ' || to_number(vday) || ' Epoch: ' ||
                 vepoch || ' Date: ' || to_char(vdate, 'mm-dd-yyyy'));
END;

Current Date: 1 Epoch: 1470009600 Date: 09-01-2016
Current Date: 15 Epoch: 1471219200 Date: 09-15-2016
Current Date: 30 Epoch: 1472601600 Date: 09-30-2016
Current Date: 31 Epoch: 1472601600 Date: 09-30-2016
```

This simply finds the last day of the month returned by the `v_today` date and compares it to the input `vday` and picks the lowest value. So, for September, if `vday = 31`, it would compare 31 with 30 (the last day in September) and output 30.

If you're dead-set on returning the first day of the month, then you'd need to change the `least` section to something like:

```
CASE WHEN to_number(to_char(last_day(v_today), 'dd')) < to_number(vday)
          THEN '01'
     ELSE vday
END
```

N.B. Note that I've made a few changes to your code to make it more robust - eg. You had `vDate  := TO_DATE(vDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');` which is a bit daft since you originally had `vDate` as a string, and by doing that, you're forcing Oracle to implicitly convert the string into a date and then back into a string.

Instead, I declared `vDate` as a date and have output the date in resultant string in the date format you used throughout the rest of the code - this means that it no longer relies on the NLS `nls_date_format` parameter to decide (this parameter is not necessarily the same for everyone!).